# Laplace transforms - second shift theorem

Tags: laplace-transform

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

Hi, i'm struggling with understanding how this expansion came about for determining the LT of f(t). Is anyone familiar with this?
thank you

Comment: Are you unclear with where the functions that they are applying the Laplace transform are coming from, or the actual step in applying the transform?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I know the second shift theorem for the unit step function (u) is being applied but I don't understand where the expansions come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your comment correctly, then I think I see the confusion.

Recall that the second shifting theorem says that if $\mathcal{L}\{ f(t)\} = F(s)$ then $\mathcal{L}\{ f(t-a)u(t-a)\} = e^{-as}F(s)$

Now, let's dissect taking the Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{2}t^2u(t-1)$. Note that our current function is $f(t) = \frac{1}{2}t^2$. So then $f(t-1) = \frac{1}{2}(t-1)^2$. As such, to get $f(t)$ in the desired form, we will conveniently add $0$ in a number of different ways:
$$f(t)=f(t) + (t-t) + (\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}(t^2-2t+1) + t - \frac{1}{2} = f(t-1)  + t-\frac{1}{2} + (\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}) $$ 
$$= f(t-1) + (t-1) + \frac{1}{2} $$
Now we have $f(t)$ in the desired form to apply the shifting theorem.

Comment: Thank you!! this was very helpful